# Creating a two dimensional array which groups sets of dateTime objects based off of the interval of time between each dateTime object

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, multidimensional-array, dateinterval

I have to create a program that takes all of the shows from a given performer and groups their shows into 'visits' which would be defined as a group of shows happening on consecutive dates. The below dateTime objects are a subset of a larger list that I spliced for the brevity of this post.

```
Array (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-04-22 12:45:49.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Denver
            )

        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-04-21 12:45:49.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Denver
            )
        [2] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-04-18 12:45:49.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Denver
            )
       )
```

I have a list of datetime objects and I need an algorithm which will place the datetime objects into a two dimensional array based upon the size of the interval between each date. If the interval between the two datetime objects is greater than 1 day, then create a array within the larger array. If the interval is smaller than 1 day, then add the datetime object to the array that the pointer is currently set on. The below algorithm created the dateTime interval multidimensional array from the three dateTime objects before.

```
    $incrementKey = 0;
foreach ($datesIntervalArray as $d) {
    if ($d->days > 1) {
        $incrementKey++;
    }
    $groupsOfVisits[$incrementKey][] = $d;



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => DateInterval Object      (1/1/2017)
                (           
                    [days] => 1
                )

            [1] => DateInterval Object      (1/2/2017)
                (
                    [days] => 1   
                )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => DateInterval Object      (2/1/2017)
                (           
                    [days] => 1
                )
 )
```

So my question is how can I take this information and create an array in the format of the second array (with the dateInterval objects) but with the information from the first array(dateTime)? I haven't been able to figure out how to convert back from dateInterval to dateTime. Is there a way of doing this without having to convert to dateInterval in the first place? I feel like I am close but have spent an ungodly amount of hours on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought the answer I gave to your question about this from the other day already did this grouping? Did I miss something?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/1hh4H

Comment: Okay wow it works! I wasn't able to get your code to work because I thought you were using the foreach to loop through the dateInterval objects, but you actually were looping through dateTime objects. Thankyou you are a lifesaver!

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. You're welcome!